# how would i target different css classes per certain items in a php array?

Tags: php, html, css, arrays

I have a PHP array such as

```
$lulz = array ( 'tom', 'hojn', 'john', 'kiwi', 'tron', 'jikes')
```

I am outputting the array as follows via simple foreach

```
foreach ($lulz as $key) {
  echo $key;
}
```

I would like to put different CSS classes per each output. so, for example, the output would be

```
$result = '<div class="one">$tom</div><div class="two">$hojn</div><div class="three">$john</div><div class="four">$kiwi</div><div class="five">$tron</div><div class="six">$jikes</div>';
```

the current path I am on is putting in an incrementer variable that is incremented ++ after each loop. that works - I get 1, 2, 3, etc - but I am not sure how to translate that to my CSS divs per each item; or if I am even on the right path.

i was hoping to output array such as:

```
foreach ($lulz as $key) {
  echo $key[1];
  echo $key[3];
}
```

where `[1]` and `[3]` are just the entry 1 and 3 in the array

but doesn't seem to be possible.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your array as a class for each output.

Try this

```
$lulz = array ( 'tom', 'hojn', 'john', 'kiwi', 'tron', 'jikes');

foreach ($lulz as $key){
  echo '<div class="'.$key.'">'.$key.'</div>';
}
```

Comment: this is perfect thank you. using the `$key` as the class name is genius.

Answer (score 1):

If you can just use the incrementer in the class name and it doesn't have to be a word representation of the number, this will give you the desired output and your classes would be `.el1`, `.el2`, etc.

```
<?php
$result = '';
$lulz = array ( 'tom', 'hojn', 'john', 'kiwi', 'tron', 'jikes');
foreach ($lulz as $key => $value) {
  $result .= '<div class="el' . ($key + 1) . '">' . $value . '</div>';
}   
echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: `$count` doesn't seem necessary in a `foreach` loop - you could easily use `$key` for the same purpose (all array items are indexed sequentially in this instance, so it's not going to break anything). It would also make more sense to have `$value` inside the `div` tag instead of `$key`. I have upvoted your answer, because you seem to have grasped what the original poster wanted far better than I did. Thank you.

Comment: @Pyromonk thanks for the feedback. I rarely use PHP. Updated - is that what you mean?

Comment: Perfect! It might be a good idea to initialise `$result` (`$result = '';`) before the loop, just to make the code a tad bit cleaner.

Comment: @Pyromonk thanks! learning new things today :) Just read about why that's a good idea. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php *"It is not necessary to initialize variables in PHP however it is a very good practice. Uninitialized variables have a default value of their type depending on the context in which they are used"*

Comment: ok wow this works great. i am using a multi-dimensional array, is that why the counter is not working for me do you think? i pasted your code and the counter works great, yet when i move to my code it just says `el1` over and over

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$lulz = array('tom', 'hojn', 'john', 'kiwi', 'tron', 'jikes');
$catz = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'five', 'eight', 'thirteen');

foreach($lulz as $k => $x) { echo '<div class="'.$catz[$k].'">'.$x.'</div>'; }
?>
```

or

```
<?php
$lulz = array(
    array('tom', 'one'),
    array('john', 'two'),
    array('hojn', 'three'),
    array('kiwi', 'five'),
    array('tron', 'eight'),
    array('jikes', 'thirteen')
);

foreach($lulz as $k => $x) { echo '<div class="'.$x[0].'">'.$x[1].'</div>'; }
?>
```